# .NET Core 2.0 Crypto sample not working - Error Cng v4.3 uses Algorithms v4.3 higher than referenced Algorithms v4.2

Tags: c#, .net-core, public-key-encryption

So I'm trying to get a sample compiling from .NET Core Api Docs [ECDsaCng Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdsacng?view=netcore-2.0).  I got compile errors about are you missing an assembly.  I downloaded .NET Core 2.0 and then added reference to newly installed `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll` and some terms turned from black to light blue showing token recgonition but I got compile errors, I'm guessing this is a versioning issue.

I started again from scratch after I installed .NET Core 2.0 in case people are wondering.  So this is a project created newly by the New Project Wizard with a fresh install.  So I'm stuck now (I'm the kind of guy who'll close all the windows and open them up again).

The code is given below.  and a typical error message is given as a block quote underneath.

```
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdsacng?view=netcore-2.0
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

//Added Dependencies/Reference to C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll;

Namespace DotNetCoreEllipticCurveDigitalSignerConsl
{
    class Alice
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bob bob = new Bob();
            using (ECDsaCng dsa = new ECDsaCng())
            {
                dsa.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
                bob.key = dsa.Key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);

                byte[] data = new byte[] { 21, 5, 8, 12, 207 };

                byte[] signature = dsa.SignData(data);

                bob.Receive(data, signature);
            }
        }


    }
    public class Bob
    {
        public byte[] key;

        public void Receive(byte[] data, byte[] signature)
        {
            using (ECDsaCng ecsdKey = new ECDsaCng(CngKey.Import(key, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob)))
            {
                if (ecsdKey.VerifyData(data, signature))
                    Console.WriteLine("Data is good");
                Else
                    Console.WriteLine("Data is bad");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1705  Assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Cng' with identity
>   'System.Security.Cryptography.Cng, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' uses
>   'System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, Version=4.3.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher
>   version than referenced assembly
>   'System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms' with identity
>   'System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, Version=4.2.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'  DotNetCoreEllipticCurveDigitalSignerConsl   c:\users\simon\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2017\Projects\DotNetCoreEllipticCurveDigitalSignerConsl\DotNetCoreEllipticCurveDigitalSignerConsl\CSC 1   Active

EDIT: Adding csproj file as per request in comments

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Cng">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

EDIT: I have manually edited csproj file to TargetFramework netcoreapp2.0 as per this blog [Rick Strahl (MVP) Upgrading to .NET Core 2.0 Preview](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/May/15/Upgrading-to-NET-Core-20-Preview)  Upon reoping the project there was a delay an in the Output window output from Package Manager said `Restoring NuGet packages...` and the status bar said `Installing Microswoft.NET.Core.App 2.0.0.`  Then the compilation error red squigglies disappeared.

And now it compiles, good news.  Bad news is there is now a runtime error

[image]

Comment: It's a console app by the way.

Comment: I don't think you can pick a single assembly out of 2.0. You need to upgrade the entire application to a netstandard2.0 (or netcoreapp2.0) to get all the assemblies right.

Comment: @ChadNedzlek : this is strictly .net core as it eventually must run on Linux, though I want to first get it working on Windows 8.1 64 bit Pro.  Also if you read the post you'll see I started the project from scratch, (via the standard menu and subsequent wizard) after .NET Core 2.0 installation and it failed.

Comment: Please include the content of your .csproj file to your question.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain : Thanks for looking at this.  I have added csproj file.

Comment: Changing the fundamental nature of the question after people have already answered and commented isn't a great idea, it makes it really confusing for people coming in later, not knowing the timeline of things.  You should open a new question for the null reference exception and close this one, as it answered how to reference 2.0 things as it was.

Comment: @ChadNedzlek : I see you work for Microsoft, would you kindly update your company's docs page re the bug fix in the accepted answer, missing line `ecsdKey.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created a new .NET Core 2 Console App on a Windows 10 machine, referenced `System.Security.Cryptography.Cng` as a NuGet package and copied your code.

I got a `NullReferenceException`. The problem is, the ECDSA algorithm doesn't seem to know the hash algorithm, as it doesn't get it from the public key... Setting it manually works for me:

```csharp
class Alice
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bob bob = new Bob();
        using (ECDsaCng dsa = new ECDsaCng())
        {
            dsa.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
            bob.key = dsa.Key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);

            byte[] data = new byte[] { 21, 5, 8, 12, 207 };

            byte[] signature = dsa.SignData(data);

            bob.Receive(data, signature);
        }
    }


}
public class Bob
{
    public byte[] key;

    public void Receive(byte[] data, byte[] signature)
    {
        using (ECDsaCng ecsdKey = new ECDsaCng(CngKey.Import(key, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob)))
        {
            // set hash algorithm manually here
            ecsdKey.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
            if (ecsdKey.VerifyData(data, signature))
                Console.WriteLine("Data is good");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Data is bad");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting this working.  [Also honourable mention to Scott]  I'll forward amendment to Microsoft, it is their code from their documentation site.

Answer (score 5):

You should not be adding direct references to files in the SDK. What you need to do is add a reference to the package [System.Security.Cryptography.Cng](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Cryptography.Cng/), then it will detect that you are using a package you have locally and use it instead of downloading a new copy.

Comment: Actually even after fixing package reference, on my mac I am getting `Unhandled Exception: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Windows Cryptography Next Generation (CNG) is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsaCng..ctor()
   at hwapp.Main(String[] args) in /Users/viktorendokimov/experiments/netcore/hwapp/Program.cs:line 11`